# Emacs bind single shift key

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I know that the `shift` key is somewhat special, but sometime it turns out this key is very handy when we have some key binding conflicts.

Currently I want to bind the single left `shift` key to replace the occupied `TAB` key, how can I make it?

;; Emacs 24.3, Mac OS X 10.9

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that it's possible to do within Emacs.

But you can do this with `xmodmap`.

Just create `~/.shift_on`:

```
clear Shift
add Shift = Shift_R
keycode 50 = U03DE NoSymbol U03DE
```

and `~/.shift_off`:

```
keycode 50 = Shift_L
add Shift = Shift_L Shift_R
```

Calling `xmodmap ~/.shift_on` will make the shift key insert `Ϟ` - a regular character
that you can bind to. Calling `xmodmap ~/.shift_off` turns off this behavior.

You can do much more with `xmodmap` if you want more shortcuts for Emacs or any other program.
It allows to assign to each key a-z 4 meanings instead of the default 2 - the *unshifted* (e.g. `a`)
and *shifted* (e.g. `A`). The two additional states are *modified* and *shift modified*.
With that you can have 72 more keys (which can be combined with Ctrl and Alt for even more key bindings).

Comment: Does this have any side effects on using normal shift?

Comment: No. The right shift will still work.